# integer to 4 bit binary php using pack function

Tags: php

How to send integer value `1` as `0001` binary in php? I am trying as `pack('I','0001')`. I have also tried `('h*','0x01')`. Output should be just 2 bytes of data.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `decbin` function:

```
$i=1
echo "00".decbin($i); //outputs 0001
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`decbin()`](http://php.net/function.decbin) function with the [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/str_pad) function to accomplish this. By using `str_pad()` versuses hardcoding the leading `0`'s, you can optionally control the length of your output, extending or reducing it at any time by manipulating the second `pad_length` argument.

```
$num = 1;
$len = 4;
echo str_pad(decbin($num), $len, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: I need to send this data to other machine listening on a port so the output should be in binary not string.

Comment: @SanjayChauhan You can try using [`base_convert()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) to change the value from a decimal (base10) string into a binary (base2) number. This is going to strip off the leading `0`'s though so it doesn't sound like what you want. To my knowledge, I don't think you can "pad" a number in PHP without formatting it as a string. By default PHP is going to strip off those `0`'s. I may be wrong on that, but I've never heard of it before.